# Swagger UI displaying as blank screen after deploying my .NET Core 2.1 web api to a development server

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, swagger-ui, webdeploy

I was able to setup Swagger UI successfully to test my .NET Core 2.1 web api on my local PC.  But after deploying the web api to a development server, the Swagger UI page is displaying completely blank on the server.  I already have started my web api program via the command prompt on the server.  I'm not sure if there are steps I need to take on the development for Swagger UI to display and work properly.

Comment: Do you get a HTTP 404 when navigating to Swagger's URLs?

Comment: When I navigate to for example: http://localhost:5000/XXXXXX/swagger/index.html, 
a completely blank browser window is displayed. No text or styling at all.